# Javascript onClick Globally

Tags: javascript

I have a web application with many forms that submit data to a MySQL Database.

On all pages i have `include 'settings.php';` so whatever i put in there will be on every page (CSS Links, JS Code etc)

Whats the best JS Code i can put in my settings.php file to put an `"onClick"` event on every single button on all pages.

I want it to do this:

```
onClick="this.disabled=true; this.value='Please Wait…';"
```

So on all forms within the site, every button that is clicked will display the `Please Wait...` text until the form is submitted

Comment: if you are listening to those buttons to catch the form submits, you should listen to the form's `onSubmit` event instead.

Comment: Ah, something solutions that have tried to target both `button` and `input` types have forgotten is that `button.value` won't change the button text.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly most of the people answering this question have never heard of event delegation.

```
window.addEventListener("click",function(e) {
    var t = e.srcElement || e.target;
    if( !t.tagName) t = t.parentNode;
    if( t.tagName == "INPUT" && t.type.toLowerCase() == "submit") {
        t.disabled = true;
        t.value = "Please wait...";
    } 
},false);
```

Comment: I was going to use `e.srcElement || e.target` too, but does it make sense inside addEventListener (considering old IE doesn't support it)? My IE skills are a little rusty.

Comment: Haha I was going to post a native js solution with event delegation... then remembered the gory days of cross-browser events. So I gave in and posted the jQuery solution (with delegation). ;)

Comment: when using this code, it works fine the but the <form action="..." doesn't complete. i just disables the button, changes the text and thats it. do i need to add something in that says like form.submit?

Answer (score 0):

You really shouldn't be using `onClick=...` Instead, bind the actions via JS:

```
document.getElementById('element-id').onclick=function(){
    alert('Hello World');
}
```

Comment: whats wrong with onClick? how do i add the submit/button disable to your code above?

Comment: Well you're embedding javascript in HTML which is a hassle to change as it's not all in one file as you've found out yourself. I would suggest reading up on javascript because this is usually the first thing you will learn: `document.querySelector('button, input[type="submit"]')`

Answer (score 0):

```
// very simple with jQuery
$(document).on('click', 'button,input[type="button"],input[type="submit"]', function (e) {
    var $this = $(this).prop('disabled', true);

    if ($this.is('button')) {
        $this.html('Please wait...');
    } else {
        $this.val('Please wait...');
    }
});
```

Comment: From the JS tag description: `Unless a tag for a framework/library is also included, a pure JavaScript answer is expected.` JQuery isn't tagged. Plus, it's also very simple with pure JS.

Comment: Ah neat, I didn't realize tags had descriptions like that. Thanks. :)

Comment: i have added this code:
$(document).on('click', 'button,input[type="button"],submit,input[type="submit"]', function (e) {
    $(this).prop('disabled', true).val('Please wait...');
});
but the form action doesn't complete - just does this action above and nothing else

Comment: a) my solution is using jQuery - if you're not using it, look at the native javascript solutions posted by others. b) About to update my solution to properly take care of `<button>` elements.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this ought to do it:

```
(function() {
    var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
    for (var i=0,len=buttons.length; i<len; i++) {
        buttons[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
            this.disabled = true;
            this.innerHTML = "Please Wait...";
        });
    }
})();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ryanbrill/5WYN9/